# How can I insulate an area without an attic above it?

Tags: insulation

My laundry room and a walk-in closet are freezing cold. They're on the ground floor in part of the house that is single-story. So, there is no attic above them. How do I insulate these areas when there's no attic access? Is the only option to pull down the ceiling, insulate, and then re-install the drywall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just like in surgeries, you can come in from either side, either take off the top or take off the bottom.  Generally speaking it is easier to take off the bottom.  However, you don't say how much of a gap there is (if you know) between the drywall and the bottom of the roof.  If you don't have enough space to put enough insulation in to make it worth your while,  then you might have to remove the roof and raise it enough to put in adequate insulation/

Comment: I cut a hatch in the garage's ceiling, crawled to the area over the house, and insulated.